# remove an element from an indexed array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array `$cc_test=array('test1','test2','test3');` .I want to remove an element 'test2' from an array and wants to get `$cc_test=array('test1','test3');` in php.

I have tried as

```
 unset($cc_test[1]);
```

I caught an error

> Cannot unset string offsets

How to remove an element from an array in php.

Comment: In that case it's not an array. With an array it works fine. https://3v4l.org/5q6vA With a string you get the error message as you say: https://3v4l.org/HO97Z

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **array_diff()** function if you want to **remove an element from an array**.

```
$a = array('test1','test2','test3');
$b = array('test2');

$result=array_diff($a,$b);
```

You will get your required output in $result. Make sure $a and $b must be an array.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (($key = array_search('test2', $cc_test)) !== false) {
    unset($cc_test[$key]);
}
print_r($cc_test);
```

Comment: array_search function searching 'test2' value in your array. if your array have 'test2' value if statement working. and unset function destroys the specified value in your array.

Comment: Please add such explanation to the code itself, such that a reader can learn from it

Comment: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/aa18fc56b9d0a6a716be5df372e29b52da2418ec

Comment: Please edit your answer to contain all relevant information, please do not use the comment section or external websites for this.

Comment: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/17cc2a3884dbae01aabed3653a513664cdf83d54

Answer (score -1):

Just like this

```
 unset($cc_test[1]);

OR

$cc_test=array('test1','test2','test3');
$del_val = 'test2';
if (($key = array_search($del_val, $cc_test)) !== false) {
  unset($cc_test[$key]);
}
```

Comment: The problem is not the unset. The problem is that $cc_test is a string and not an array.

Comment: I tried it works, can you tell me what's the problem?

Comment: Off course it works **if the variable is an array** but as you can see from the error message in question, it's not an array, it's a string